# How to have jQuery tabs with (partially) shared contents?

Tags: jquery, tabs

I've got a web site where four different kinds of data are shown, based on the tab selected below them.

Some of the tabs need shared controls. Sliders and the like. I don't want to duplicate them on multiple tabs, because that would require syncing also their runtime status all the time.

I presume I must make my own implementation for such a "tabs with shared contents". Anyone already had this need (and possibly solved it)?

Answer (score 1):

Make Your own simple tabbing solution (3 upto 10 lines of code I suppose)
[or find one that supports classes the way You need]

Instead of putting content in divs called `tab1`, `tab2` etc. use paragraphs and give them classes that refer to content. Then make Your tabs solution show paragraphs with classes associated with the tab

Or in a simpler case - make tabs show onlu paragraphs that have a class `tabX` and give multiple classes to some paragraphs.

done.